# Django fails on "unexpected keyword argument 'allow_blank'", even though I'm following documentation

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I tried adding the possibility for empty fields for one of my models, I get the following error-message: "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allow_blank'"

What I tried doing was adding the keyword "allow_blank=True" to both a TextField and a CharField. Same error in both instances.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Set(models.Model):
    pass


class Chat(models.Model):
    setID = models.ForeignKey(Set, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chatID = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Message(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chatID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    messageID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    createdDate = models.DateTimeField()
    createdBy = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    messageDate = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Tag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="tags",
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    value = models.TextField(max_length=None, allow_blank=True)
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    flagged = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What I want to do is allow an empty field in my Tag-model, so if there is a better way to do this, please do tell.

Comment: Please paste a link to the Django documentation page in which you see allow_blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is nothing called `allow_blank` in Django, its only `blank`

```
value = models.TextField(max_length=None, blank=True)
```